# Is there a $p$-adic version of Liouville theorem?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, analyticity

That is, if a function $f$ is analytic and bounded in all $K$, a $p$-adic field (or more generally a complete non-archimedean field), has to be constant?
And does the theorem work for functions on $K^n$, or in $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: "Analytic" means what?  Since the space is zero-dimensional, there are certainly sets $U$ that are open and closed, not empty and not the whole space.  The characteristic function of such a set is identically constant on a neighborhood of every point.  Note that the answer says "entire" and not "analytic"...

Comment: Please do not deface your questions. Others may have the same question too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to the first question is *yes*, Liouville's theorem still holds *for valued fields that are algebraically closed* (this last part added after Pete Clark's comment below). See, for example, [these lecture notes](http://wcherry.math.unt.edu/pubs/pfunc.pdf) by William Cherry (in particular, see page 16).

Comment: Note that Cherry's result is for a valued field which is **algebraically closed**, e.g. $\mathbb{C}_p$.  If I remember correctly, there are nonconstant bounded entire functions on $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (or any finite extension thereof), just as there are on $\mathbb{R}$.  I believe Alain Robert's GTM has a discussion of this.

Comment: In fact, in any normed field, the nonexistence of nonconstant bounded entire functions implies that every nonconstant polynomial has a root, so algebraic closure is necessary as well as sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, I just need the case of an algebraically closed field.

Comment: Theorem 42.6 in Schikof's _Ultrametric calculus_ seems to be relevant.